# How to convert my date time format into date time ? I am using string as my datatype

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am retrieving data from the database, but my date is not showing properly:
[image]

In my controller, I am retrieving the data like this:

```
DateOfBirth = Convert.ToString(Tbl.Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"])
```

In my model class:

```
 public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `string` for a `DateTime` property. And what do you mean _its not showing properly_ - what are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting only date not date time. Is it possible to convert into proper date without changing the datatype string.?

Comment: Use `.ToString("d");` to format it as a `string` (but your property should be `DateTime`, not `string` and format it in the view (using a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

if you want only date part as string use this

```
yourDateTime.ToShortDateString()
```